# Updating a list item using date() function

Tags: javascript, date-time, list-item, update

I have a column [ScheduleTime] which is a `DateTime` type in my List. Using JavaScript i need to update the [ScheduleTime] column which should be Current Day whenever my script loads. But here I need to update [ScheduleTime] column's Date only. Time should remain same. I am gonna use `set_item` function.

Please help me out on this.

```
var collListItem;


ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

 function retrieveListItems() {


sucess();


var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Master Task Summary');





var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ScheduleTime'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='true' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");


this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function sucess()
{ 

   var clientContext1 = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

    var oList1 = clientContext1.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Master Task Summary');

var varlist= oList1.getItemById(86);

alert("1st");

   var scheduleTime = new Date(varlist["ScheduleTime"]);

alert("2st");

var today = new Date();

var newScheduledTime = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), scheduleTime.getHours(), scheduleTime.getMinutes(), scheduleTime.getSeconds(), scheduleTime.getMilliseconds());

 alert("3st");
 varlist.set_item('ScheduleTime', newScheduledTime);
alert("4th");
 varlist.update();
alert("5th");

  clientContext1.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceed), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 

  }

function onQuerySucceed()
{
alert("Update USccess");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of JavaScript Date Object for that.

For example, while reading the data

```
var scheduledTime = new Date(oListItem["ScheduledTime"]);
```

Now you can calculate the new Time as follows

```
var today = new Date();
var newScheduledTime = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), scheduledTime.getHours(), scheduledTime.getMinutes(), scheduledTime.getSeconds(), scheduledTime.getMilliseconds());
```

Now while saving use `newScheduledTime`

```
oListItem.set_item('ScheduledTime', newScheduledTime);
oListItem.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

**Update based on edit**

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
var item;
var clientContext;
var oList;
function retrieveListItems() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Master Task Summary');
    item= oList.getItemById(86);
    clientContext.Load(item,"Include('ScheduleTime')");
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceed() { 
    alert("Item Retrieved"); 
    var scheduleTime = new Date(item.get_item('ScheduleTime'));
    alert(scheduleTime);
    var today = new Date();
    var newScheduledTime = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), scheduleTime.getHours(), scheduleTime.getMinutes(), scheduleTime.getSeconds(), scheduleTime.getMilliseconds());
    alert(newScheduledTime);
    item.set_item('ScheduleTime', newScheduledTime);
    item.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onUpdateSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
}

function onUpdateSucceeded() {
    alert('Updated');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response . var scheduledTime = new Date(oListItem["ScheduledTime"]); Is this mandatory to include in code?

Comment: And also in the third statement var newScheduleTime  =new Date(today.getDate()); is enough rgt? Because i need to update only current day not Time.Is that fine?

Comment: I am trying this. Thanks. I will update once it is done

Comment: Request failed. The string was not recognized as a valid datetime. There is a unknown word starting index 1.Undefined.

Comment: You can add couple of alert statements and debug

Comment: it is working upto update() statement. it is not executing onQuerySucceeded method. It is executing failed method.

Comment: Yes. I have added my code.Please find in the edit tab.

Comment: I have updated my answer.