# Date is correct, but String is not being recognized as a valid datetime

Tags: list, javascript, date-time, formatting

I use this to get the current date with one month added to it:

```
var date = new Date();
day = date.getDate();
month = date.getMonth() + 1;
month = month + 1;
if((String(day)).length == 1)
    day = '0' + day;
if((String(month)).length == 1)
    month = '0' + month;

dateT = day+ '.' + month + '.' + date.getFullYear();
console.log("dateT: " + dateT);
```

Using `console.log("dateT: " + dateT);` I get `14.02.2020`.

I have a method that adds an element to a list on SharePoint.

There I use `var posDeliveryDate = dateT;` and then `oListItem.set_item('DeliveryDate', posDeliveryDate);`, but I get the error that the String was not recognized as a valid datetime.

I've seen that there are lots of threads regarding this issue, but what do I have to change in my case?

I tried `day = date.getDate().toDateString();` but that didn't help and I can't use `DateTime.ParseExact()` in JavaScript..

Even when I manually enter a date, such as `"14.02.2020"` instead of `posDeliveryDate`, I get the error.

2 weeks ago the code worked, but now suddenly I get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below lines of code:

```
dateT =new Date(date.getFullYear(),month, day) ;
var posDeliveryDate = dateT;
oListItem.set_item('DeliveryDate', posDeliveryDate);
```

Now the `dateT` will be in the correct format to be inserted into SharePoint list.

For more information, refer below link:

[Updating a list item using date() function](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130028/updating-a-list-item-using-date-function).

Comment: Again, you saved me hours of trial and error. Thanks a lot !!